# Swashbuckle IOperationFilter for query parameters class doesnt work with nested classes

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've build custom `IOperationFilter` based in this [article](https://tkit.dev/2020/03/10/complex-get-query-param-objects-in-swashbuckle/).

It works ok with simple examples like this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetModels([FromQuery]Parameters parameters)
 {
     ...       
 }

public class Parameters
{
    public int PageSize {get;set;}
    public int PageNumber {get;set;}
}
```

But when I try to set complex parameters like this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetModels([FromQuery]ComplexParameters parameters)
 {
     ...       
 }

public class Parameters
{
    public int PageSize {get;set;}
    public int PageNumber {get;set;}
}

public class ComplexParameters
{
    public string Contains {get;set;}
    public Parameters Pagination {get;set;}
}
```

I got problem that swagger creates RequestUrl with brackets for nested class:

`https://Url/Path?contains=string&pagination[pageSize]=0&pagination[pageNumber]=0`

Comment: And what did you expect the URL to be in such case?

Comment: Found a workaround, made my class inherit from `PagintationParamaters` class